# Is there any possible do upsert functionality in "array of an object" using firestore query?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

```
Example :[{
  inst:"EVA",
  std:"12th"
},
{
  inst:"KSF",
  std:"12th"
}]
```

[image]

As per the above example, In my case if "inst: "EVA" is already there in the "qualification" array so we need to update the object from the existing one.
Then "inst: "KSF" does not already exist in the "qualification" array so we need to add that one.

Help me if there is any way to upsert using firestore query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "upsert" operation for objects in arrays.  If you need to make changes to that array, you will have to read the document, modify the contents of the array in memory, then update the document with the new contents of the array.

Arrays of objects usually do not work the way that people want, given their limitations on querying and updating.  It's usually better to store data as documents in a nested subcollection, so they can be more easily queried and updated by the contents of their fields.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, I'll try to change the collection structure like nested subcollection for my scenario.